# GAE-JEE Subclasses works in local but not online

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, charts

I'm trying to deploy an application (Google App Engine+JEE) online. It works very well with Eclipse but Google Charts don't work online (however, other parts of the application works).

I have two kind of errors, the first is for an "**annotationchart**" :

> *Error: Server Error*
>
> *The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
> Please try again in 30 seconds.*

With error on log:

> *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A collection with at least one value is required.*

The second is for a "**stacked bar chart**" with no error on log:

> *Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string*

I'm working with jdk1.7.0_67, setted as a compiler and "*-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javaw.exe*" is in first line in my **eclipse.ini**

It seems like my **subclasses** (what are used in the second chart) are **not working online** on the appengine.google.com Datastore. **But it works on localhost**...

To explain the problem, in local this code works:

Servlet:

```
Country fr=ofy().load().type(Country.class).filter("name","France").first().now();
            LicenseCountryCondition a=new LicenseCountryCondition("AEZZ52", 1, fr);
            LicenseCountryCondition lic=ofy().load().type(LicenseCountryCondition.class).filter("name", "AEZZ52").first().now();    
            req.setAttribute("test", lic);
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/testCountryCondition.jsp" ).forward( req, resp );
```

Jsp:

```
<body>
${test.name}
</body>
```

In local the web page returns:

> AEZZ52

Online, it returns:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

This is my first application on Google App Engine, I don't understand how it can work in local but not online. If I forget something or else, please tell me.

Comment: Without showing relevant code is impossible to help you.

Comment: Show where you build the data table

Comment: Its likely a problem with the data types in the table

Comment: I edited my message adding some code, trying to reduce it as I can. But if it was a data type problem, how could it work in Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry but waaay tldr. Make a minimal sample thst shows the issue. Debug it clientside and see what the charts library is complaining about in your input data array

Comment: Edited, I think the problem is not from charts but only from the subclass :/

Comment: The subclass is presented like: 
`@Index
@Subclass(index=true)
public class LicenseCountryCondition extends License{
 Ref<Country> country;

[...]`

(if it can help)

Answer (score 0):

I get what was wrong. It was only the parent class what have to got an indexed list of enum of it's subclasses (**The indexation worked well on Eclipse but less online**).